# How to upload pdf to firebase storage with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I'm using latest [firebase_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage) version now some methods and references of storage are updated `ploadTask.onComplete` does not support.

so how do I get uploaded pdf url?

Piece of code:

```
 Future<String> uploadPdfToStorage(File pdfFile) async {
    try {
      Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('pdfs/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}');
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(pdfFile, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'pdf')); 
    String downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
  


   final String url = await downloadUrl;


  print("url:$url");
  return  url;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?  If there is an error message, you should add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an edited code that should work with the latest firebase `storage_package`:

```
Future<String> uploadPdfToStorage(File pdfFile) async {
  try {
    Reference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('pdfs/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}');
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(pdfFile, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'pdf'));

    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;

    String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    print("url:$url");
    return url;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```